# An integral and an infinite sum of incomplete Gamma functions

Tags: calculus, integration

While trying to evaluate the integral $\int \frac{dx}{x+e^x}$, we see that:
$$ \int \frac{dx}{x+e^x} = \int \frac{1+e^x}{x+e^x}dx  - \int \frac{e^{x}}{x+e^x}dx.$$

Now, the first integral on the RHS is of the form $\int \frac{dv}{v}$ and can be evaluated easily. Coming to the second one,

$$ \int \frac{e^{x}}{x+e^x} dx= \int \frac{dx}{\frac{x}{e^x}+1}. $$ We can expand the integrand and write it as an infinite sum:

$$ \frac{1}{\frac{x}{e^x}+1} = 1-\frac{x}{e^x}+\frac{x^2}{e^{2x}}-\frac{x^3}{e^{3x}}+\dots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^ne^{-nx}.$$

The integral of each of the term in the series can be represented as an incomplete Gamma function as $$\int x^ne^{-nx}dx=\frac{\Gamma(n+1,nx)}{(-n)^{n+1}}.$$

However, I don't see possible any further simplification. Suppose it was a definite integral with limits $|x|<1$, then can we say anything more about the integral?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There should be $(-1)^n$ in front of final integral to match result given.

Comment: @JamesArathoon thanks, but I think the alternating sign can be taken care of by the (-1)^{n+1} factor in the denominator. Even if that isn't the case, can the infinite sum be simplified in any meaningful way?